# SQL time between communication

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, datediff

hi Guys hope you are all Safe,

I have a table in SQL with time-stamps and I would like to calculate the time between 2 communications after i order them DEC

I have looked everywhere but unfortunately without any success :(
The desirable outcome should be same as the yellow columns

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the difference using `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (timestamp - lag(timestamp, 1, timestamp) over (order by timestamp)) diff_interval
from t;
```

I don't know if converting the interval to minutes is an important part of your question.

If second-precision is sufficient, you can use:

```
select t.*,
       (timestamp - lag(timestamp, 1, timestamp) over (order by timestamp)),
       extract(epoch from (timestamp - lag(timestamp, 1, timestamp) over (order by timestamp))) / 60.0 as minutes
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you mate, this statement runs but I still get the result as TIMESTAMP instead as decimal or minutes

Comment: FYI,  extending the answer by @GordonLinoff somewhat. Your statement  "but I still get the result as TIMESTAMP" in incorrect. When you subtract timestamps you do get a timestamp you get an interval (which Gordon handeled). While timestamps and intervals visually may appear the same they are quite different. For example you cannot add timestamps but you can add intervals and add intervals to timestamps. see [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-interval/)

Comment: @Belayer . . . Yassine was correct.  I had neglected to do the subtraction when I first answered.